# Nodemon watch triggers webpack dev middleware rebuild

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, nodemon, webpack-dev-middleware

I am using [webpack-dev-middleware](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware) along with expressjs to watch and serve files emitted from webpack.

Have setup expressjs server with [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) so that it can watch any server code changes.

The issue is, for any change detected by nodemon, the server restart also triggers a new `webpack-dev-middleware` execution which then rebuilds the entire client bundle.

Express server snippet used in development:

```
const express = require('express');
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js');

const app = express();
const compiler = require('webpack')(webpackConfig);
const devMiddlewareInstance = require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
  publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
});

app.use(devMiddlewareInstance);

app.listen(300, function() {
  console.log('App listening on port 3000!\n');
});
```

Is there any way to prevent the execution of `webpack-dev-middleware` for every restart triggered by nodemon ?

Comment: same issue have you any idea for resolving that ?

Comment: @Kalifornium : Nope. This is as per design of `nodemon` and as it restarts the entire node process `webpack-dev-middleware` can do nothing about it. The workaround would be to keep it in a different static server and maintain another nodemon server for APIs. That is what `webpack-dev-server` is doing.

Comment: ok then , we should open an issue for that !, i've tried Chokidar it's better for some features !